# AskUbuntu email notification not working

Tags: discussion, bug, email

I had had my AskUbuntu profile's email setting 
set to "notify me every three hours" for unread 
AskUbuntu email messages but never received any 
notifications about email messages that have been 
sitting there, unread, for about two weeks. 
Nothing in my actual inbox, nor my spam folder. 

So, how do I find out when someone's answerd a 
question of mine? I thought this was the method
to use to receive notification that "I've got mail."

I just now changed it to daily notification. 

Dr Doug

Comment: Where did you set your email preferences?

Comment: profile > preferences > inbox emails > email me my unread inbox messages every three hours. After setting it to every day, it appears to be working, because your answer generated a notification in my email inbox.

Comment: That's odd.  Now that you mention it I haven't been getting emails either.

Comment: Looks to me as if the three hour setting might be broken. That's my best guess, anyway. If yours is set to every three hours, then that may be indicative.

Comment: Mine is set to daily, but I'm pretty good at getting my notifications quickly so perhaps I just never have day old notifications. Try changing the setting.

Comment: Yup. I did the change of settings before you suggested it, and it seems to have fixed it. I'm now receiving notifications. <br><br> It still irks me though that it wasn't working correctly at first. That should at least be recorded somewhere in case there are multiple occurrences of it happening. I understand it's not a deal breaker, but if it's providing data to developers (even if it's something that's intermittent) then it seems worthy of taking note. Thoughts?

Comment: Posting here is notifying the developers ;)